# Angular - How to make new HTTP requests based on previous request's results

Tags: angular

I am using Github API to retrieve a list of user's public repositories

```
https://api.github.com/users/<username>/repos?per_page=100&page=<page_number>
```

The API results are paginated and a max of 100 items can be returned per request, so I am trying to iterate pages and stop when I receive an empty array.

This is how I am doing it right now,

```
public userRepositoryData: BehaviorSubject<RepositoryInfo[]> = new BehaviorSubject<RepositoryInfo[]>(null);
private temp: RepositoryInfo[] = [];

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
}

public getUserRepositories(username: string): void {
    this.getRepositories(username, 1);
}

private getRepositories(username: string, pageNumber: number): void {
    if (username) {
        this.httpClient.get(this.getRepoEndpoint(username, pageNumber)).subscribe((repos: RepositoryInfo[]) => {
            if (repos && repos.length > 0) {
                repos.forEach(repo => {
                    repo.created_at = new Date(repo.created_at);
                    repo.updated_at = new Date(repo.updated_at);
                    this.temp.push(repo);
                });
                this.getRepositories(username, pageNumber + 1);
            } else {
                this.userRepositoryData.next(this.temp);
                this.temp = [];
            }
        });

    }
}

private getRepoEndpoint(username: string, pageNumber: number): string {
    return `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=100&page=${pageNumber}`;
}
```

**My question:** Is there a better way of doing the same? (preferably using some RxJs operator maybe)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use **switchMap** for that, switchMap emits Observable after applying the given function to each item emitted by source Observable

```
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
...

this.httpClient.get(this.getRepoEndpoint(username, pageNumber)).pipe(
    tap((repos: RepositoryInfo[]) => {
        if (repos.length < 1) {
          this.userRepositoryData.next(this.temp);
          this.temp = [];
        }
      }),
    switchMap((repos: RepositoryInfo[])) => {
        if (repos && repos.length > 0) {
            repos.forEach(repo => {
                repo.created_at = new Date(repo.created_at);
                repo.updated_at = new Date(repo.updated_at);
                this.temp.push(repo);
            });
            return this.getRepositories(username, pageNumber + 1); // must return an Observable
        } 
    })
).subscribe();
```